# Tooltip with Bootstrap not Styled as is shown in example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have tried using the example code that is provided by the Twitter Bootstrap docs,

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="first tooltip">Hover over me</a>
```

and although I do get the hover over effect, it doesn't look like the pretty version that bootstrap provides. I have tried looking this up in Google and Stack Overflow, but most of them offer solutions on how to customize the look of the tooltip. I would just like to use the default look bootstrap provides.

Any thoughts on why mine may be looking like the screenshot below?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Clear your cache.
2. Make sure bootstrap.min.css file reference is not broken or other files.
3. Go to your dev tool and verify if there are specifics errors we can go over.
4. Make a prototype using the same conditions as your example so that you can identify your 
   problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this. Also check using inspect element that your customised classes are not overriding the default CSS.

```
<a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="first tooltip" data-original-title="first tooltip">Hover over me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

also make sure you are adding the correct bootstrap css and javascript seems like either you don't have them or their path is wrong